# How do i isolate certain numbers from a string in python?

Tags: python

```
'8 -9.7521970601311E-5 1237.16 1265.50" spec2 = "2 59 0 9810.07016902'
```

From the above case, I only want to extract the value **`-9.7521970601311E-5`**. How would I do that?

Comment: Is your constraint to extract every 2nd term from the string?

Comment: You can do this `your_string.split(" ")[1]`

Comment: split the string on space and take the second element? it is unclear which criteria you intend to use to select what you want to extract.

Comment: ☝️ Or: `float(your_string.split(" ")[1])` if you need it as a float

Comment: I do not necessarily want to extract the 2nd term from the string always but yes that is the general idea. I just want to know how to extract certain terms from a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> str1 = '8 -9.7521970601311E-5 1237.16 1265.50" spec2 = "2 59 0 9810.07016902'
>>> float(str1.split()[1])
-9.7521970601311e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by indexing:

```
y = '8 -9.7521970601311E-5 1237.16 1265.50" spec2 = "2 59 0 9810.07016902'

x = y[2:21]

print(x)
```